# How can I get live data from another site to my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to find a plugin that can help me or a set of scripts that can help me to get data from another site to mine. I am not a developer, however, I know there has to be a way I to do that. specifically, let's say from Walmart or sears I want to get product's live prices and description and picture because the prices change very frequently and I need an exact price always displaying on my site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use simplehtmldom, You can get any type of data by setting up the simplehtmldom parser.

[Simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart)